# How to trigger jQuery when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Does anyone know a reliable way to listen out for a window closing event in javascript/ jQuery?

The window is the parent and not any child instances.  I.e. if a window is closed by mistake and the visitor launches their browser again and loads the url previously visited once more.

Comment: Are you trying to save state in an AJAX site?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window.unload event to set a cookie or use local storage to save the time using new.date(), then see if the visitor returned within a set amount of time.

Something like:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    localStorage.setItem(“theyLeft”, new Date());
}
```

then on load check for :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var timeGoneBy = new Date() - localStorage.getItem(“theyLeft”);
    //calculate time gone by, and do something if visitor returned within given time etc.
}
```

Would need to be refined a lot, and local storage should have cookies as fallback, but just to show the jist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) method.

> The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates
>   away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could
>   have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the
>   address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event.
>   Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even
>   a page reload will first create an unload event.

You can also try playing with the JS onunload and onbeforeunload events.

Comment: This event also gets fired if the user clicks a link.

Comment: And many other things... see my update.